# Multi-threading with xargs warning xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value

Tags: bash, xargs

I have an xargs command in a bash script.  The script runs, but this warning is returned

```
xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value
```

Script:

```
function post_thing {
        token=$2
        ##check file exists
        if [ -f $1.thing.json ];
                then
                        response=`curl  -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}"  'https://url.com' --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$2"'' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @$1.thing.json`
                        mv $1.thing.json $1.thing.json.$response

                else
                echo "File not found: $1.thing.json"
        fi

}
export -f post_thing
seq 100 200 | xargs -n2 -P100  -I {} bash -c 'token='"$token"'; post_thing "$@" "$token"' _ {}
```

I don't understand if it's impacting the script, or what I need to do. It appears as though the script is working as expected.  Is there an issue with calling a function with xargs?

I don't get this error on my Mac, but on ubuntu, it comes up.  Hope you can help, pretty new to xargs...!

Comment: `xargs -n2  -I {}` how do you want this to work? `ignoring previous --max-args value` So remove `-n2` and done

Comment: On Ubuntu, you are surely using the GNU version of `xargs`, but the standard `xargs` on MacOS is BSD-derived and not wholly equivalent.  You cannot rely on them to emit the same diagnostics, or to emit diagnostics under all the same circumstances.  And as for the `-n` option in particular, it has different meaning to MacOS `xargs` than it does to GNU `xargs`, so if you want to write a portable script using `xargs` then you must avoid the `-n` option.

Answer (score 5):

> this warning is returned
>
> ```
> xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value
> ```

The text of the warning seems pretty clear to me.  The only trick is that `xargs` is reporting it about `--max-args`, where the command in question actually uses the short form of that option, `-n`.  The warning says that the given option is being ignored.

> I don't get this error on my Mac

On MacOS you will be using its BSD-derived version of `xargs`.  On Ubuntu you will be using GNU `xargs`.  These are not 100% compatible.

Whether that's an issue depends on the details of the command being executed via `xargs`.

> It appears as though the script is working as expected.

I doubt that, at least on Linux.

> Is there an issue with calling a function with xargs?

You're not calling a function with `xargs`.  You're running a `bash` command.  There is no particular problem with this, nor with that `bash` command executing a function exported from the parent shell.

Your `post_thing` function depends on receiving (at least) two arguments.  By default, `xargs` consumes as many input items as you give it, up to a very large limit, and feeds them as arguments to the same command.  The `-n` argument, which in GNU `xargs` can also be spelled `--max-args`, sets the maximum number that will be used in each execution of the specified command.  That GNU `xargs` is ignoring that means that if you give, say, four input items instead of two, then `xargs` will pass all of them to *one* `bash` command, instead of passing two of them to one `bash` command and the other two to another.

As GNU `xargs` says, the problem is that `-I` conflicts with `--max-args` (`-n`).  The `-I` option specifies a symbol that is to be replaced by *one* input item, and it implies that only one input item will be used in each execution of the specified command.  That's clearly not what you want.  But you don't need `-I` here.  The default is for `xargs` to place the arguments at the end of the command, which is what you want anyway.  Thus, **for Linux, you should remove the `-I {}` option** and the corresponding `{}` token at the end of the command:

```
seq 100 200 | xargs -n2 -P100 bash -c 'token='"$token"'; post_thing "$@" "$token"' _
```

For MacOS `xargs`, `-I` and `-n` both mean something slightly different. `-I` specifies a symbol that will be replaced by some number of input items *all from the same line*, and `-n` specifies a maximum number of items that will be consumed from any input line.  The two work together there, but *they do not accomplish your apparent objective* of passing exactly two arguments to each child `bash` command.  To make that work, you'll need to group items two per line.  I think you can write one command that works in both places like so:

```
seq 100 200 |
    sed -e 'N; s/\n/ /' |
    xargs -L1 -P100 bash -c 'token='"$token"'; post_thing "$@" "$token"' _
```

The `sed` command joins consecutive pairs of lines with a space character.  The `-L1` instructs both versions of `xargs` to use only the input items from one line in each command it executes.  The combination of those moots `-n2` for both version of `xargs`, though for slightly different reasons.

Note that even with that, you will still have an issue with the last command if the total number of input items is odd.